# What's the difference between --param="value" and "--param=value"?

Tags: shell

In the past I've read (can't recall the source) that:

```
./script --param="value"
```

can have different results compared to:

```
./script "--param=value"
```

and that due to these differences (which might become apparent when switching systems/OSes/distributions/shells), you should always do `--param="value"`. That is, do what I call "late quoting" (put the quote around the trailing part, or the minimal subset; don't quote the whole thing).

I've also seen people do this when modifying variables (i.e. `PATH=/bar:"$PATH"`, compared to `PATH="/bar:$PATH"`). In general, I would say that from what I've seen others do, "late quoting" is more common than quoting the whole thing.

My question is: is there really a potential difference between `--param="value"` and `"--param=value"`? If I need to quote something, is there really a difference between quoting just part of it and quoting the whole thing?

I tend to do `--param="value"` rather than `"--param=value"`, but I do it mostly because I think it's easier to mentally parse, not because I'm aware of any technical differences.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference, at least in the particular cases you've mentioned. The shell will strip out the `"` characters, and the end result is the same. To debug shell quoting issues, I sometimes use a simple program that just prints out its argv. For example,

```
$ printargs --param="value"
argv[0] = printargs
argv[1] = --param=value

$ printargs "--param=value"
argv[0] = printargs
argv[1] = --param=value
```

Here's the code, for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the shell-script equivalent: `printargs(){ local arg; for arg; do echo "$arg"; done; }`

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Better use `printf` in the script, too; otherwise `printargs -n` will surprise you.